# Connecting through authenticated proxy

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi, proxy

I have an Unrooted Sony Xperia tipo running 4.0.4.
I have a Wi-Fi at home which uses an authenticated proxy. I have managed to apply the proxy and also have managed to use authentication.
The trouble.
Any app on my phone is unable to use the Wi-Fi.
Is there any way I can at least get Google Play running without rooting my phone?

Comment: How did you apply the proxy settings.
(This is really a comment. Can a mod please change it)

Comment: @JasjeevSingh A comment after 12 days! Well, I used the advanced settings which can be opened by ticking the advanced setting check box, when first setting up the connection with WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Drony](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sandrob.drony).
If you need any help regarding how to configure, [this](http://code.google.com/p/sandrop/wiki/HowToUseDronyWithOtherProxy) can help.